# javascript - Uncaught ReferenceError: keys is not defined

Tags: javascript

I am getting an error when I run the following command in an included script. But if I run the command from the google chrome console, it works properly.

```
var a = {};
console.log(keys(a));
```

Error:

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: keys is not defined
```

What's going on here?  How can I use the `keys` function in an included script?

Comment: Many functions in javascript are predefined . For example'length' property. a = [1,2] . a.length returns 2. Here, keys is a function that returns the keys of an object in array format. It is working when i run the commands in console but getting that error when i use 'keys'  function in the script file.

Comment: Why is this downvoted so much? It's a legitimate question that, if I myself were inexperienced with JS debugging, I'd be quite perplexed as well. And enough information is given to accurately describe the problem. I'd say its a good question.

Comment: This question made perfect sense to me - I came here when exactly the same thing happened to me. `keys` worked in the console, but not in the code. One of the answers below explained it.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
console.log(keys(a))
```

`keys()` is not function provided by the browser for use in your code.  You probably want `Object.keys()`

```
a = {};
console.log(Object.keys(a));
```

Sometimes the console has extra functions exposed to it for ease of use debugging that aren't available in your actual code. `keys()` sounds like one, and `copy('some text')` is another.

I'm failing to find a link which lists them, sadly. But I'm quite sure there are more than those 2 functions.

Comment: I agree that this question is constructive. I don't do a lot of Javascript and just had this exact same question. Namely, "Why am I getting this error on the keys function when I just debugged my code 2 seconds ago in the Chrome debugger?"

Now I know.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you get an error like this, try to search for a definition of the function/variable that's been reported as undefined. If it *is* defined, try looking for a reason this might not be working. Did you know that the `keys` function is apart of the `Object` constructor? You can't call it as if it's a free-standing function. Though if you get into the habit of doing this, try making your own function to allow this:

```
function key( object ) {

    return Object.keys( object );

}
```

Your code should pass given a definition like this.